# targetModel.updateMany is not a function When I delete File ( Strapi + Mongo DB )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I have a problem with the strapi delete file.

I can upload file.
if I want to delete an uploaded file it returns error: "Internal Server Error" from the response, but the file is deleted.

Where am i doing wrong ?

Error logs:

```
[2021-10-21T19:37:46.827Z] error TypeError: targetModel.updateMany is not a function
at C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\lib\relations.js:487:38
at CoreDocumentArray.map (<anonymous>)
at CoreDocumentArray.map (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\documentarray.js:42:27)
at C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\lib\relations.js:464:42
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.deleteRelations (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\lib\relations.js:393:25)
at deleteOne (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\lib\queries.js:560:17)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Object.delete (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-database\lib\queries\helpers.js:15:18)
at async destroy (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-plugin-upload\controllers\upload\api.js:55:5)
at async C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\router\utils\routerChecker.js:79:22
at async module.exports (C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-plugin-users-permissions\config\policies\permissions.js:88:3)
at async C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi-utils\lib\policy.js:68:5
at async C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\parser\index.js:48:23
at async C:\Users\gizem.ay\Documents\Projects\personal\waa-backend\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\xss\index.js:26:9
```

[2021-10-21T19:37:46.830Z] debug DELETE /upload/files/6171c17b24b4715ba01791af (3267 ms) 500

Error in my project " error TypeError: targetModel.updateMany is not a function "

Code in React js :

```
export const deleteFileById = async (fileId) => {
return await axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:1337/upload/files/${fileId}`, {
        headers: {
             Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
   });
```

}

Code in Strapi strapi-connector-mongoose\lib\relations.js:487:38 :

```
 if (Array.isArray(entry[association.alias])) {
          return Promise.all(
            entry[association.alias].map(val => {
              const targetModel = strapi.db.getModelByGlobalId(val.kind);
              // console.log(targetModel);
              // ignore them ghost relations
              if (!targetModel) return;

              const field = val[association.filter];
              const reverseAssoc = targetModel.associations.find(
                assoc => assoc.alias === field
              );

              if (reverseAssoc && reverseAssoc.nature === 'oneToManyMorph') {
                return targetModel.updateMany(
                  {
                    [targetModel.primaryKey]: val.ref && (val.ref._id || val.ref),
                  },
                  {
                    [field]: null,
                  },
                  { session }
                );
              }

              return targetModel.updateMany(
                {
                  [targetModel.primaryKey]: val.ref && (val.ref._id || val.ref),
                },
                {
                  $pull: { [field]: primaryKeyValue },
                },
                { session }
              );
            })
          );
        }
```

And my package.json file dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
"knex": "0.21.18",
"mongodb": "^4.1.3",
"sqlite3": "5.0.0",
"strapi": "3.6.8",
"strapi-admin": "3.6.8",
"strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.6.8",
"strapi-connector-mongoose": "^3.6.8",
"strapi-connector-mongoose-modified": "^3.1.9",
"strapi-hook-mongoose": "^3.0.0-beta.17.8",
"strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "^3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-i18n": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.8",
"strapi-utils": "3.6.8"
```

},

Comment: What is the targetModel, and where you create/set it?

Comment: I think it is the model found in the database.
 const targetModel = strapi.db.getModelByGlobalId(val.kind);

Comment: Well, it may be that there is no such model with provided `val.kind` that is why it returns `undefined` and hence you see the error.

Comment: I edited my Relations.js file.You can see above. I typed my TargetModel into console and got the result. Worked second update updateMany function and this got the " targetModel.updateMany is not a function " error

Comment: I wonder if you misconfigure some model? Maybe you just made a mistake when creating models, and e.g. provided Schema instead of a proper Model.

Comment: this project was made with strapi. I did not create any custom models in project code. I used only strapi admin panel. Maybe I made a mistake while creating the project with strapi + mongo.
I will try create new project. Thank you so much for your attention

Comment: Edit: I fixed this issue. What have I done ; First of all, I deleted the file in the item. Then I completely deleted the file I uploaded. And the response gave no errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant solution (Fixed the code a little):

1. Install the package

> npm i patch-package -D

2. Add a script to package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

3. In the Strapi root folder, create a folder with the file

> patches/strapi-connector-mongoose+3.6.8.patch

4. Open the strapi-connector-mongoose+3.6.8.patch file and paste the following content there and save and close file (Formatting and indentation should be like this)

```
diff --git a/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js b/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js
index 411046a..a0c535e 100644
--- a/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js
+++ b/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js
@@ -473,7 +473,7 @@ module.exports = {
                   );
 
                   if (reverseAssoc && reverseAssoc.nature === 'oneToManyMorph') {
-                    return targetModel.updateMany(
+                    return strapi.db.getModel(targetModel.modelName).updateMany(
                       {
                         [targetModel.primaryKey]: val.ref && (val.ref._id || val.ref),
                       },
@@ -484,7 +484,7 @@ module.exports = {
                     );
                   }
 
-                  return targetModel.updateMany(
+                  return strapi.db.getModel(targetModel.modelName).updateMany(
                     {
                       [targetModel.primaryKey]: val.ref && (val.ref._id || val.ref),
                     },
```

5. Now we enter

> npm i

6. Launching Strapi and testing image deletion